# Why doesn't Typescript handle overloads of functions with identical signatures?

Tags: typescript

Overloaded functions differing only by return types would have been VERY useful. The inferred return type of a call would be the union of the return types of all overloads.

For example:

```
interface A {
  fn(): string
}
interface B {
  fn(): number
}

declare let x: A & B;
x.fn() // returns number | string in my dreams
       // returns number in reality

interface C {
  fn(): string
}
interface D extends C { // error - D incorrectly extends C
                        // wish this was okay
  fn(): number
}

declare let y: D
y.fn() // would return number | string
```

Why did Typescript make this decision?

**Background:**

I'm writing a type safe SQL query builder.

When you start, a root query builder will be of type `Select & Update & Insert & Delete` so that it has access to the methods of all query types.

Methods have a set of possible output types. For example, the range of `where()` is { Select, Update, Delete } and the range of `update()` is { Update }.

Given a base type and a method call, the resulting type is the union of the base type and the intersection of the range of the  method.

So if when you call `where()` on the root query builder, the new query builder type is:

```
(Select & Update & Insert & Delete) | (Select & Update & Delete)
  = (Select & Update & Delete)`
```

If you then call `update()`, the new query builder type is:

```
(Select & Update & Delete) | (Update)
  = (Update)
```

Unfortunately, this design is purely theoretical since Typescript doesn't correctly resolve overloads with identical signatures.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `x: I<number> | I<string>`?

Comment: It's correct as is. Added more details.

Comment: I think something could be worked out using mapped and conditional types..

Comment: That's because overloads are weird. They don't perfectly factor into the type system like normal type expressions.

Comment: I ended up working around this issue be enumerating all the possible states of the query builder and writing an interface for each possible state.